# Is there a way to perform XML transformations in Erlang?

Tags: xml, erlang, xslt

How can I produce an XML from another XML through XSL transformations? I looked at `xslapply/2` but I want to generate XML not Erlang code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's said in the documentation of [xmerl_xs](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/xmerl_xs.html) module (regarding `xslapply/built_in_rules combo)`:

> This approach is probably easier for an Erlanger but if you need to
>   use real XSLT stylesheets in order to "comply to the standard" there
>   is an adapter available to the Sablotron XSLT package which is written
>   in C++.

To my surprise, most links I've found were broken, but here's a [working one](http://forum.trapexit.org/viewtopic.php?p=30202). Take note, though, that it's only an *adapter*, and therefore requires installation of the main [Sablotron package](http://www.gingerall.com/charlie/ga/xml/p_sab.xml).